# Install BingMapAppSDK.msi with visual studio 12?

Tags: silverlight, installation, maps, bing-maps, bing

I want to install the Bing Silverlight Extended Mode Beta, but it looks like it is only possibly if I install VS 10 and Silverlight 4.

I am working with VS 12 and Silverlight 5.

I already tried to reinstall all Silverlight packages and only install the Silverlight 4 Toolkit.
Unfortunately, it does not work.

best,
David

Answer (score 0):

The Bing Maps Silverlight Extended Mode Beta never made it out of beta. It is not recommended to use this control as it is filled with bugs.